# Drupal: How can I redirect anonymous user to 404 rather than 403?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

This is on Drupal 7. I have some content I want to 'hide' (as opposed to publish/unpublish) from anonymous users.

Someone has made a check box (`$hidden_value`) to do this already, but it's redirecting to 403.

```
$access = !$hidden_value['value'] ? user_access('access content') : !user_is_anonymous();
```

I want to make this redirect to the 404 page and so within `hook_preprocess_page()` I added:

```
  if ($access === FALSE) {
    drupal_not_found();
  }
```

but this does not seem to work - It still redirects to 403. I also tried `drupal_exit` to the same result.

Would anyone know what I can do to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use hook_node_view()

```
function hook_node_view($node, $view_mode) {
  if (!user_is_logged_in()){
    drupal_not_found();
  }    
}
```

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_view/7.x